# uso de clases comunes en django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo una modelo que maneja imágenes, y que se ve reflejada en la DB en una tabla:

```
class Imagen(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imagen = models.ImagenField(upload_to='Imagenes/Producto/prod_/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'imagen'
        verbose_name_plural = 'imagenes'
        db_table = 'imagen'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + " - " + str(self.ancho) + "X" + str(self.alto)
```

El modelo `Producto`, usa esta imagen en una relación uno a muchos (1 producto puede tener varias imágenes).

Esto funciona correctamente, pero ahora me encuentro con que necesito manejar imágenes para otro modelo, entonces se me ocurre usar el mismo modelo `Imagen`... acá me enfrento a 2 problemas:

1. El modelo `Imagen`, esta acoplada al modelo `Producto`
2. Quiero que el modelo `Imagen`, sea una clase genérica, que pueda usar para cualquier modelo.

¿Como se hace esto en Django? estoy algo perdido en este punto.
¿Existe alguna otra solución mas elegante que la que estoy proponiendo?

Answer (score 1):

Django dispone del framework ContentTypes para ese tipo de situaciones. Deberías usar una Generic Foreign Key

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1